# Trouble deleting cookies within symfony

Tags: php, jquery, cookies, symfony

I have a php file that uses jquery.  I have this file store cookies if a check box is checked after the submit button is pressed and delete the cookies (if they exist) if the checkbox is not checked.

It works perfectly fine on my development server, which does not have symfony on it.  When I transfer it over to our live server, which requires me to place the code in symfony, it saves the cookies but it does not delete them.  I am using the jquery.cookies.js from here [LINK](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

and my code is simply

```
                   // else delete the cookies if the checkbox is unchecked
                    else
                    {
                        ?>
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                            $.removeCookie('vtuid');
                            $.removeCookie('vt_usr');
                            $.removeCookie('vt_pd');
                            $.removeCookie('vt_chk');
                        </script>
                        <?php
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B default symfony set cookie with flag http only, that mean - you can`t delete cookie from js.
for example:

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('blabla', 'true', time() + (3600 * 48), '/', null, false, false));
```

Comment: Ok I figured it was something like that.  What I did for a work around was to set cookies of the same name with empty values so that they are deleted after the session ends.

Answer (score 30):

You can also do

```
 $response = new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
 $response->headers->clearCookie('nameOfTheCookie');
 $response->send();
```

Don't forget to send the response back in the order that the cookie will be deleted

Answer (score 1):

The full documentation for setting cookies in Symfony is here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#setting-cookies

Clearing cookies is described in the API documentation:
http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html#method_clearCookie